# Android - AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-calendar

I'm currently making a native Android app and I have code working to schedule a notification to appear on the device using the AlarmManager class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotifyActivity.class);     
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, alarmIntent);
```

Two things:

1. The notification goes off every time the app is opened. I don't want this to happen.
2. The notifications is suppose to be going off at 9am device time (or so I'm led to believe). This is not happening and it looks like it goes off every 9 hours or so.

Can anyone tell me why the notification goes off every time the app is opened and why the notification is not **only** being triggered when the device reaches 9am?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the doc of [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be
>   triggered immediately

You are setting your alarm to 9:00 , if you launch after this hour, trigger time is in the past, so the alarm is going off when the app is opened.

You can check if the current time is after alarm, if so, you add one day to the alarm and it will going off the next day. For example:

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

        if (cal.before(cal_now)) {//if its in the past
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, alarmIntent);
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: thanks for the comment. The time was always set in the future, but I do wonder if device some how though the time had past. Will look into your suggestion